# See child account opportunities under parent account

Tags: opportunity, related-list

We have a parent-child account structure and we only log our opportunities under the child account. However, we would like to see the opportunities of all child accounts under the parent - is that possible without code? 
Has anyone done that before?
Tia, Lily

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. Create a lookup to Account on Opportunity called Parent Account
2. Update the lookup field to parent account of the account of Opportunity if it is not null. This can be done via Process Builder or Trigger.
3. Add the related list of Opportunities on the parent account. You should be able to see all the opportunities from child account as well.

This is the bare minimum of customization that needs to be done to achieve what you want.